# $.holdReady(hold) is deprecated what is the replacement for it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have the following code where I'm loading and updating the config dynamically

```
$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("econfig",function(){
  $.holdReady(false);
})
```

This holdReady has been deprecated, so what function can I replace?

Couldn't find any solution for above

Comment: [Take a look of documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Went through it, didn't help much

Comment: $.when( $.ready, customPromise )
  .then( function() {
    // main code
  } )
  .catch( function( error ) {
    // handle errors
  } )

how to pass custom promise

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2f73Lnyx/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `script.onload` JavaScript for loading scripts with callback.

Here you get separated access on the JS loading.

#### Try below Code

```js
function addScript(url, id, callback) {
    // Check if the script has already been added
  if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
      // Create a script element for the script
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.id = id;

      // Add the onload event handler
    script.onload = function() {
        // Call the callback function when the script has finished loading
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback();
      }
    };

      // Add the script element to the head section of the page
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
}

console.log("initiate");
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", (event) => {
  if (event.target.readyState === "interactive") {
    console.log("Page ready");

    addScript(
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js",
      "jquery-script",
      function () {
        console.log("jquery loaded");
      }
    );
  }
});
```